# A jQuery question about variables and selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lately, I have been doing this in an effort to speed up performance (and sometimes it helps with maintainability)

```
var objectToReference = $('div .complicated #selector ul:last');
```

So what does `objectToReference` really hold? Sometimes things have bitten me, so I've gone back to using the full selector and it has worked.

So does the variable hold a reference, a pointer, etc (I'm not sure the exact definition of those terms)

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A best practice that many people use when they create a variable like this is to name it starting with $, to indicate that it is a jquery object. So you could name the variable $o, and you can directly call other jQuery chain functions after it, without having to put $() around the variable.

```
$o.hide();
```

It is a good idea to start with the surrounding element for the area you are manipulating, to avoid having to search the entire document. For example, to get all links within a single section of the document (without having to search the whole document):

```
var $o = $('#mysection');
var $links = $('a', $o); // equiv to $o.find('a')
```

Finally, it never hurts to pass a jQuery object back through jQuery:

```
$o === $($o)
```

This has a nice side effect - you can write a function that accepts any of the following as an argument: a selector, an element, or a jQuery object:

```
function myFunc(e) {
    var $e = $(e);
}
// All of the following will work:
myFunc('#mysection');
myFunc(document.getElementById('mysection'));
myFunc($('#mysection a'));
```

Comment: OH NOES! Now my JS looks like a perl or php.
Good tip tho :P

Answer (score 3):

The return value of a **[jQuery selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)** is an array of jQuery elements. If the selector does not find any matches, then it contains an array with 0 elements.

Each element in the array is essentially a reference to the matching DOM element in the HTML document. This is what allows you to traverse and manipulate them as needed.

Comment: Technically not an array but an object given a few array-like properties.

Answer (score 1):

It holds a jQuery collection, which is an array. You may have gotten in trouble if the DOM changed on you.

---

Looked into it a bit further and found that the collection (which you can treat like an array) is an object with array-like properties.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/12/peeling-away-the-jquery-wrapper-and-finding-an-array

Keep in mind that arrays and objects are very much alike in JavaScript. For more, see my [Kirk & Cheesecake post](http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/how-weird-are-javascript-arrays/).

Answer (score 1):

It holds a reference to the jQuery object that was returned. Any changes to the object change the underlying DOM element and all other references to the same element.

```
$('div .complicated #selector ul:last')
```

Your variable `objectToReference` will be a jQuery object that you can perform jQuery operations on. Also, even though you don't have to, you can also use `objectToReference` to create a new jQuery object, which shouldn't impose any performance limitations since it should just return a reference to itself and not re-search for that element.

```
var objectToReference = $('div .complicated #selector ul:last');
var copyOfObject = $(objectToReference);
```

You may have run into problems by trying to reference DOM properties of the `objectToReference`. If you want to get at the underlying DOM element of your `objectToReference` returned by the jQuery selector, you can do this:

```
var objectToReference = $('div .complicated #selector ul:last');
var domOfObject = objectToReference.get(0);
```

Or optionally, you could do this, which does the same in 1 line:

```
var domObjectToReference= $('div .complicated #selector ul:last').get(0);
```

Again, you can use the `domObjectToReference` in the jQuery constructor to create another reference to that object:

```
var objectToReference2 = $(domObjectToReference);
```

All of these examples store references to the DOM element. If you modify the value of one of the references, they will all be modified/updated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested I've published V2 of a jQuery reference if you want to have a look at that it's here: http://www.skidoosh.co.uk/jquery/jquery-selectors-and-attribute-selectors-reference-and-examples-v2/ for jQuery 1.2 I'll be updating it for 1.3 in a few days.